# How to display thumbnail image with article header?

Tags: php

i would like to display an image with my news header.(website  like.lt,you can check it out)
Currently in home page i can display only header and short description, once u click on the header you are able to read full article and see image.So i would like to be able to show  same image in the home page? this is a index.php part wich displays articles:
That's the article.php

```
<?php 
include('config.php');

//Create site settings variables            
$sitequery = 'select * from settings;';
$siteresult = mysql_query($sitequery,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$siteinfo = mysql_fetch_array($siteresult);
$siteurl = $siteinfo['url'];

$article = $_GET['id'];

      if (!is_numeric($article)) {
          header('Location: '.$siteurl); 
     }

    else

    {   

$sitequery = 'select * from settings;';
$siteresult = mysql_query($sitequery,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
    //Create site settings variables        
$siteinfo = mysql_fetch_array($siteresult);
$sitetitle = $siteinfo['title'];
$siteurl = $siteinfo['url'];
$sitecomments = $siteinfo['comments'];
$commentmod = $siteinfo['commentmod'];

$query = "select * from articles where status=0 and id = ".$article;

$articleresults = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($articleresults);
$articleinfo = mysql_fetch_array($articleresults);

if (!$num_results) {
    header('Location: '.$siteurl);
}

    //Get article info  
$id = $articleinfo['id'];
$authorid = $articleinfo['authorid'];
$date = strtotime($articleinfo['date']);
$artdate = date('m/d/y', $date);
$categoryid = $articleinfo['categoryid'];
$title = stripslashes($articleinfo['title']);
$body = stripslashes($articleinfo['body']);
$resource = $articleinfo['resource'];


   //Meta Info
$cathead = 0;
$metatitle = $title." - ";
include('header.php'); 
include('sidebar.php'); 


if ($seourls == 1) { $scrubtitle = generate_seo_link($title); }


    // Setup the article template
$articletemp = new Template("templates/".$template."/article.tpl");

    // get author info
$authorquery = "select * from authors where id=".$authorid;
$authorresult = mysql_query($authorquery,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$authorinfo = mysql_fetch_array($authorresult);
$authorname = $authorinfo['displayname'];
$authorbio = $authorinfo['bio'];
$gravatar = $authorinfo['gravatar'];
if ($seourls == 1) { $scrubauthor = generate_seo_link($authorname); }

    // get category info
$catquery = "select * from categories where id=".$categoryid;
$catresult = mysql_query($catquery,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$catinfo = mysql_fetch_array($catresult);
$categoryname = $catinfo['name'];
$catparent = $catinfo['parentid'];
if ($seourls == 1) { $scrubcatname = generate_seo_link($categoryname); }

    // if the category doesn't have a parent
if ($catparent == NULL) {
    if ($seourls == 1) { // With SEO URLS
        $displaycat = "<a href=\"".$siteurl."/category/".$categoryid."/"
                      .$scrubcatname."/\"><b>".$categoryname."</b></a>";
    } else {
        $displaycat = "<a href=\"".$siteurl."/category.php?id=".$categoryid
                      ."\"><b>".$categoryname."</b></a>";
    }

   // if the category DOES have a parent
} else {
    $query = "select * from categories where id=".$catparent;
    $result = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $info = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $parentname = $info['name'];
    if ($seourls == 1) { $scrubparent = generate_seo_link($parentname); }

    if ($seourls == 1) { // With SEO URLS
        $displaycat = "<a href=\"".$siteurl."/category/".$catparent."/"
                    .$scrubparent."/\"><b>".$parentname."</b></a> > 
                      <a href=\"".$siteurl."/category/".$categoryid."/"
                      .$scrubcatname."/\"><b>".$categoryname."</b></a>";
    } else {
        $displaycat = "<a href=\"".$siteurl."/category.php?id=".$catparent
                      ."\"><b>".$parentname."</b></a> > 
                       <a href=\"".$siteurl."/category.php?id=".$categoryid
                       ."\"><b>".$categoryname."</b></a>";
    }
}


   // Add a view to this article
$query = "select * from articleviews where articleid = ".$article;
$results = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$viewinfo = mysql_fetch_array($results);
if ($viewinfo == NULL) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO articleviews VALUES (".$article.", 1)";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
} else {
    $totalviews = $viewinfo['views'];
    $totalviews++;

    $sql = "UPDATE articleviews SET views=".$totalviews." WHERE `articleid`=".$article."";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
}

if ($seourls == 1) { // With SEO URLS
    $authorlink = "<a href=\"".$siteurl."/profile/".$authorid."/".$scrubauthor."/\"><b>".$authorname."</b></a>";
} else {
    $authorlink = "<a href=\"".$siteurl."/profile.php?a=".$authorid."\"><b>".$authorname."</b></a>";
}

    // Setup all template variables for display 
$articletemp->set("authorname", $authorname);
$articletemp->set("authorlink", $authorlink);
$articletemp->set("date", $artdate);
$articletemp->set("displaycat", $displaycat);
$articletemp->set("views", $totalviews);
$articletemp->set("title", $title);
$articletemp->set("body", $body);
$articletemp->set("gravatar", $gravatar);
$articletemp->set("resource", $resource);

// For the adcode
$query = "select * from adboxes where id=1;"; 
$result = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$articletemp->set("250adcode", stripslashes($info['adcode']));


 // Outputs the homepage template!

echo $articletemp->output();

  //Displays the comments -- if admin has them enabled

if($sitecomments == 0) {
echo "<br/><h2>Comments</h2>";

require_once 'comments/classes/Comments.class.php';

/* Article ID which shows the comments */
$post_id = $article;

/* Level of hierarchy comments. Infinit if declared NULL */
$level = NULL;

/* Number of Supercomments (level 0) to display per page */
$supercomments_per_page = 10000;

/* Moderate comments? */
if ($commentmod == 0) {
    $moderation = true;
} else {
    $moderation = false;
}

# Setup db config array #
$db_config = array("db_name" => $db_name,
   "db_user" => $dbusername,
   "db_pass" => $dbpassword,
   "db_host" => $server );

# Create Object of class comments
$comments = new Comments($post_id, $level, $supercomments_per_page, $moderation, $db_config);

# Display comments #
echo $comments->getComments();
}

include('rightsidebar.php'); 
include('obinclude.php'); 

    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to copy the code from article.php. There are no answers just because you didn't mentioned where you get the data from and what the path is for you images.

If you are able to post the code where the variables like $id, $authorname, ... are set and the code of your article.php, I'll be able to help you further.

Comment: Thank you for your respond i added article.php to my first question

Comment: Are you sure you can get the path to your thumbnail? I've scaned the code and haven't seen anything like image. I suppose the image is hardcoded in the "body" you are getting from your database.

Comment: yes that's right image is coded in the 'body' is there any way i could change that?

Comment: You can create an extra column in you DB-table you are using for articles, and store the path to your image there per article.

Comment: Ok once i will create column im my DB how should i change the code?sorry i am not really expierienced . Thank you for your help

Comment: The things yo'll have to do: 1: edit the add-article script (add an extra insertfield into DB => imagepath) 2: After doing it you'll get the thumb in new column. You can use this value then to display your image.